# Output newline char in regexp under Java or ANT

Tags: java, regex, ant, replace, newline

I have ant target that invokes replaceregexp task

```
<target name="regexp.replace">
    <replaceregexp file="${file.temp}"
                   match="(.*)"
                   replace="first operation on \1  second operation on \1"
                   byline="true"/>
</target>
```

file.temp is

```
A1
A2
```

desired output is

```
first operation on A1
second operation on A1
first operation on A2
second operation on A2
```

What to insert as new line char for producing desired output in ant replaceregexp  parameter?

```
 replace="first operation on \1 %NEW_LINE% second operation on \1"
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
<replaceregexp file="test.txt"
               match="(.*)"
               replace="first operation on \1${line.separator}second operation on \1"
               byline="true"/>
```